# Controller / player does not rotate when jump on rock

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one eliptical shape rock which is rotating around own center and I want to jump on that rock.
When I jump my player / controller does not rotate together with that rock. I have capsule colider on my rock but checkbox Is Trigger is not checked.
When I checked it is just pass through rock. Hot to make that controller / player when jump on rock rotate together with rock ?

Comment: You are using Unity3D's Character Controller?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski I am using for character also capsule collider

Comment: Does character have nonkinematic rigidbody?

Answer (score 0):

I must say I didnt find any solution using only physics.

Unity3D physics engine dosnt support *this* kind of rotating (to my knowladge). First I thought it is becouse of shape of player's collider (capsule) couse it has only one point that is touching other collider (the one that is rotating). But I checked also with box collider and the object (player) didnt rotate too.

So you will not get this just with physics.

There was an answer here but was deleted with solution. This solution was to assign parent to player gameObject. This parent will be this rotating object (rock). Thanks to this player object will recive all movement from rock.

You should assign the rock as parent to player when collision is detected. [OnCollisionEnter(Collision)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)

```
player.transfrom.parent = rock.transform;
```

And set the parent of player to null when player leaves the collistion. [OnCollisionExit(Collision)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html)

```
player.transfrom.parent = null;
```